# Get Custom Taxonomy ID Assigned To Page

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to get the term ID of the custom taxonomy a page on my website is assigned to.

So I have a page that's assigned to a term "Seventeen" under the custom taxonomy "Clip Category". So I'm looking for the ID of the term seventeen.

Here's the code I've got so far with some help from one kind StackExchange use:

```
                <?php
                    $slug = $post->post_name;
                    echo $slug;
                    $term = get_query_var($slug);
                    echo $term;
                    $taxonomy = get_query_var('clipcat');
                    print_r($taxonomy);
                    $termid = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy );
                    echo $term->term_id;
                ?>
```

The code gets stuck right after echoing the $slug variable, as can be seen on this page: http://noellesnotes.com/portfolio/seventeen/

Answer (score 1):

You do it wrong. `$slug = $post->post_name;`is mean you take slug of page, not slug of term.

You should take **all** terms from page `<?php get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy ); ?>` and then you can work with it. You will stuck in trouble fell free to ask me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_query_var`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to retrieve the public query variable in the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class of the `global $wp_query` object

You'll need the term and taxonomy name. The best practice to keep this dynamic is to use `get_query_var('term')` to get the term slug and `get_query_var('taxonomy')` to get the taxonomy slug. This will be fed back into [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get the term ID of the current term being displayed

```
<?php 
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
    echo $term->term_id; 
?>
```

Comment: I've been trying this method, but something seems to go wrong. I've detailed the code in an edit of my original question! Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you get using my code. I've tested this code in my taxonomy page and the ID of the current term is displayed. Are you using this code as is like you should.